# Dropdown menu is not fully functional (bootstrap4.0)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I am trying to create a simple drop-down menu using bootstrap beta version 4.0. All I am using is the original code found in the bootstrap documentation. The code includes the necessary cdns in order for bootstrap to work. While also jquery is implemented. Can not find the reason why this is happening. Any help, please? Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">



  <!--Fontawsome-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="about-us" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Story</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Team</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--Jquery-->

  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap Script-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Mod Script -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include Bootstrap CDN (Content Delivery Network) and you must also include jQuery.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did add the code that was required for the drop-down menu to run. However, it ain't responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You should include neceesry CDN s as in [Bootstrap 4 document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and bootstrap 4 CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--Fontawsome-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="about-us" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Story</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Team</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--Jquery-->

  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--Bootstrap Script-->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!-- Mod Script -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if you take a close look I have already implemented these in my code. I have added the propper js link yet still it ain't responsive. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: responsive means? you mean your full navigation bar? or just only dropdown mednu?

Comment: the dropdown menu.

Comment: dropdown menu is always responsible , can you show me in a image whats wrong